# Emojis in Segmented Control

Tags: xcode, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, emoji

I have emojis used in the different segments for my Segmented Control. When I select a segment, the selected segment highlights (indicates which one was selected), and the emoji suddenly becomes all white. Is there anyway to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: [Works for me](https://s31.postimg.org/ykhb6sxbf/works_for_m.jpg). Can you include a screenshot and code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use follow code and it worked for me.

[image]

OC:

```
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Swift:

```
let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["","","moon"])
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:.Selected)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a segmented control connected to my controller, so I was unsure if I put it in the action or outlet, but I put it in the viewDidLoad() and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the coding for emoji is not compatible with UIViews.

What you can do is select Momentary for the State. It will still disappear on click but will quickly come back.

Unfortunately the segment won't stay hilighted blue like you probably want though.

[image]